# mailchimp hidden input field

Tags: html, forms, bots, mailchimp, hidden-field

`Mailchimp` signup forms include a line of code, which should have effect on form bot signups, but as far as I could try it out it has no effect at all.

It goes like this:

```
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - 
do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="text" name="a_123456789_123456789" tabindex="-1" value="">
</div>
```

If I make the `<input>` tag visible and fill it in (which real people should not do), then nothing happens! Mailchimp technical support couldn't help me! Does anybody have experiences with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some kind of simple anti-bot feature.

Probally lots of bots fill all input field in form and if this field gets submitted to MailChimp they can know that there is high probability of malicous activity.

So you should just leave it as is.